# UITableView Unexpectedly Found Nil inconsistently occurring

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been stumped on this problem for a few hours now and would really appreciate any help. I'm trying to loop through every cell in a table view upon a button click and grab information from text fields in those cells. I'm using the following code to loop through the cells:

```
for i in 0...tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)-1 {
        let index = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        let cell: TextInputTableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! TextInputTableViewCell
        if let name = cell.NameTF.text, let playerHandicap = Int(cell.HandicapTF.text!), name != "" {
            result = true
            handicaps[name] = playerHandicap
       } else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter all values", message: "Please enter a name (text) and handicap (number) for each player", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is that differing row counts produce different outcomes even for the i = 0 case. For example, with 4 rows, this works perfectly fine, however with 12 rows I get an "unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an Optional value" error on the cell initialization line ("let cell") when i = 0.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I'm now trying to save each text fields value after text is edited, instead of iterating through each cell upon a button click.

My cell class:

```
protocol CustomDelegate: class {
    func nameEntered(tag: Int, text: String)
    func handicapEntered(tag: Int, text: String)

}

class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var NameTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var HandicapTF: UITextField!

    weak var delegate: CustomDelegate?

    @IBAction func NameTextEntered(_ sender: UITextField) {
        delegate?.nameEntered(tag: sender.tag, text: sender.text!)
    }

    @IBAction func HandicapTextEntered(_ sender: UITextField) {
        delegate?.handicapEntered(tag: sender.tag, text: sender.text!)
    }

}
```

And in my view controller:

```
class HandicapViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomDelegate {

// .....

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextInputCell") as! TextInputTableViewCell
        cell.NameTF.tag = cellCount
        cell.HandicapTF.tag = cellCount
        cellCount += 1

        return cell
    }

// .....

func nameEntered(tag: Int, text: String) {
        if var cellInfo = cellInputs[tag] {
            cellInfo[0] = text
            cellInputs[tag] = cellInfo
        } else  {
            let cellInfo = [text, ""]
            cellInputs[tag] = cellInfo
        }
    }

 func handicapEntered(tag: Int, text: String) {
        if let handicapInt = Int(text) {
            if var cellInfo = cellInputs[tag] {
                cellInfo[1] = text
                cellInputs[tag] = cellInfo
            } else  {
                let cellInfo = ["", text]
                cellInputs[tag] = cellInfo
            }
        } else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Value", message: "Please enter only whole numbers as your handicap.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

I've found that the action functions are being hit in the cell class but the calls to the nameEntered and handicapEntered functions aren't making it to the view controller.

Comment: As always, do not misuse the view (cell) as model (data source). `cellForRow` returns `nil` if the cell is off-screen. Get the data from the model. And never call delegate methods like `numberOfRows` yourself. Get the information from the data source array, too.

Comment: Delegate is not set     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextInputCell") as! TextInputTableViewCell              cell.delegate = self And UITextField doesn't not have IBAction, implement shouldChangeCharactersIn textField delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an Optional value
```

This happened because you have tried to loop through cells. `UITableView` does not create as many cells you asked it to. It will create only as many cells that can be shown in a screen. These cells are reused with new values when you scroll.

Use `protocol` delegation for these purposes.

```
protocol CustomDelegate: class {
    func buttonClicked(cell: CustomCell)
    func textEntered(tag: Int, text: String)
}

class CustomCell {
    weak var delegate: CustomDelegate?

    @IBAction btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.buttonClicked(cell: self)
    }
}

extension CustomCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let text: NSString = textField.text as NSString? ?? ""
        let finalString: NSString = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

        delegate?.textEntered(tag: textField.tag, text: finalString)

        return true
    }
}
```

In ViewController, there are a lot of ways to save these values, a basic way would be

```
var name: String!
var mobile: String!
var country: String!
var age: String!

let nameTag = 25
let mobileTag = 26
let countryTag = 27
let ageTag = 28
```

cellForRow data source method,

```
let cell = .....
cell.delegate = self

// Set respective `tag`s for `UITextField` here
cell.inputFieldOne.tag = // here
cell.inputFieldTwo.tag = // another here
```

Conform to `CustomDelegate` method,

```
extension ViewController: CustomDelegate {
    func buttonClicked(cell: CustomCell) {
        // get your data here, 
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) 
    }
}

func textEntered(tag: Int, text: String) {
    if tag == nameTag {
        name = text
    }
    else if tag == mobileTag {
        mobile = text
    }
    else if tag == countryTag {
        country = text
    }
    else if tag == ageTag {
        age = text
    }
}
```

There are lot of ways to save data from cells, this is just a basic way.

Comment: Ok, thank you that makes sense. If I'm not mistaken, would this code be for an application where each cell has a button within it? I have a button below the table view and need to return all cells when that is clicked. I thought maybe I could use your implementation the same way by having the IBAction point to that button in the cell class and then each cell would call it, but just tried and am not able to.

Comment: what are you trying to do by returning all cells?

Comment: I have two text inputs in each cell and would like to retrieve their values

Comment: Whenever text is entered in those `UITextField`s, you should save them and use that data. You should not look to retrieve cells, thats a bad idea. Check edited answer for reference.

Comment: I wasn't able to get your exact example working but I tried an implementation that is very similar. It seems like I'm doing something wrong with the way I use the delegate because the functions in the view controller aren't being reached, does anything catch your eye in the edited question?